# Matrix with invariant factors

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

Consider a multi-diagonal matrix with invariant factors along the diagonals :
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & 0 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & 0 \\
a_2 & a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & 0 & \dots & \dots& \dots & 0\\
a_3 & a_2 & a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & 0 & \dots &\dots&  0\\
0 & a_3 & a_2 & a_1 & a_2 &a_3 & 0& & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots& \vdots \\
0 & \dots & 0& a_3& a_2& a_1 &a_2&a_3 & 0\\
0 & \dots & \dots& 0& a_3& a_2 &a_1&a_2&a_3\\
0 & \dots & \dots& \dots& 0& a_3 &a_2&a_1&a_2\\
0 & \dots & \dots& \dots& \dots& 0 &a_3&a_2&a_1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Are there some nice properties about the inverse of this matrix ?
Can we say that the inverse has invariant factors along the diagonal ? Is the inverse formulation independent of the rank of the matrix ?

Comment: A matrix that is constant along its diagonal is called Toeplitz. Yours is additionally symmetric. If you search for properties of symmetric Toeplitz matrices, you'll find some papers, also about their inverse. For example [1] or [2].

[1] http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379588903266
[2] http://journal.austms.org.au/ojs/index.php/anziamj/article/download/493/357

Comment: @lhf: It's not a circulant matrix. Notice that the bottom left and top right corners of the matrix are all $0$'s.

Comment: @Florian : Thanks for telling the name of such matrices. And thanks for the links. ;)